# macOS project’s fonts are not scaling

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

**Issue:** I’m creating a macOS app in Xcode and the fonts will not scale up and down. I have tried the target’s Mac, Mac Catalyst, and Mac (Designed for iPad). Neither of these targets will work.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create a new Xcode project.
2. Build and run the new project under any of the above mentioned Mac targets.
3. In Xcode tap on environment overrides
4. Notice that “Dynamic Type” is missing

**Side note:** "Dynamic Type" is used for scaling font on iOS simulators. With this being missing when pointing to a Mac Target. This implies to me there must be another way to scale fonts.

**Expected result:** When adjusting font scale using the method given above, the font on the app should scale up and down accordingly.

**Actual result:** There appears to be no way to adjust the font scale

**Question:** Am I supposed to implement some sort of font scaling API for Mac fonts to scale?

**Code:**
App.swift file:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MACOSApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift file:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your code or project???

Comment: I have posted your Question to right place, checkout - https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/468901/486790

Comment: @ChrisR - I have added the code for you. It is the exact code you would get when building a new Xcode project. Alternatively, you can also follow my "Steps to Reproduce".

Comment: @HEMANTKUMAR - I appreciate the repost for visibility. For awareness, I have removed the "Alternate steps to reproduce" given that after updating MacOS to Sonoma 14.3, I saw that those steps are no longer possible to follow. So you may want to edit your post accordingly.

Comment: @HEMANTKUMAR Why did you post a duplicate of this programming question on Ask Different? You should delete that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/accessibility#Text-display) macOS does not support DynamicType:

> In iOS, iPadOS, tvOS, visionOS, and watchOS, use Dynamic Type and test that your app’s layout adapts to all font sizes.

You can increase text size (and contrast etc.) in the **system settings**, and it will e.g. influence font size in sidebars. There might me a way to read the settings special font size and implement it manually in your other content.

But it's not as naturally integrated as with iOS.

Comment: What's annoying about this is that macOS 14 (Sonoma) now has a Text Size setting. It's a shame that macOS apps on Sonoma don't support Dynamic Type sizing.

Comment: Please note that the apps on macOS such as Mail, Notes, and Finder respond to the change in the "Text Size" setting far more than just the sidebar.

Comment: I just came across @ScaledMetric ... that should help also on macOS – https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scaledmetric